# Sorting array has no effect

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an `double` array using `Arrays.sort(array)`:

```
double[] myArray = {-5.502E-5, -6.854E-5, -1.920E-5, -2.121E-4, -2.587E-6};
double[] myArrayCopy = myArray;
Arrays.sort(myArrayCopy);
```

But nothing changes in `myArrayCopy`. It stays unsorted. What could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you think it stays unsorted? It doesn't when I try your code.

Comment: I got sorted array `-2.121E-4
-6.854E-5
-5.502E-5
-1.92E-5
-2.587E-6`

Comment: Same here. Check if you are printing the array elements correctly.

Comment: Also be aware that `myArrayCopy = myArray` doesn't copy the array, so `sort(myArrayCopy)` is the same as `sort(myArray)`.

Comment: Take the following numbers double[] myArray = {-1.0E-0, -1.0E-1, -1.0E-2};
and map them to the number ray. You will see that everything is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the array is sorted or not, you can insert new number 2 into array. To copy an array, you can use Arrays.copyOf:

```
    double[] myArray = {-5.502E-5, 2, -6.854E-5, -1.920E-5, -2.121E-4, -2.587E-6};
        double[] myArrayCopy = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length);;
        Arrays.sort(myArrayCopy);

        for (double n : myArrayCopy) {
            System.out.print(" " + n);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (double n : myArray) {
            System.out.print("" + n);
        }
```